# html form action condition in python

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
<form action="{%url if page_related_data.task is view 'insert_register_form_values_in_database'
            or 'registered_user_data_edited' registered_user_edit_or_delete_all_information.id%}" method="post">
```

I actually want to use 2 methods

1. insert_register_form_values_in_database;
2. registered_user_data_edited (with argument registered_user_edit_or_delete_all_information.id)

but if i want to use them in one html page in one form tag how can i use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use if/else statement inside `url` template tag. Instead, you can do something similar to:

```
{% if page_related_data.task is view %}
  <form action="{%url 'insert_register_form_values_in_database' %}" method="post">
{% else %}
  <form action="{%url 'registered_user_data_edited' registered_user_edit_or_delete_all_information.id %}" method="post">
{% endif %}
```